# Most efficient method to get key for a value in a dict

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of objects:

```
dic = {'k1':obj1, 'k2':obj2, 'k3':obj3, ...}

class MyObject:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
```

I wonder how I can have the best implementation for finding the key that corresponds to a value. Something equivalent to:

```
def find_key(dic, val):
    for k,v in dic.items():
        if v==val:
            return k
    return None
```

NB: Sorry if this is obvious, I am a newbie in Python :-)

Comment: what if multiple keys have that value?

Comment: if you had googled it, you'd have found this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504258/find-key-for-value-in-python-when-key-associated-with-multiple-values

Comment: If you intend to reverse mappings often, I would suggest you look at the following questions on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863935/a-data-structure-for-11-mappings-in-python and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063319/reversible-dictionary-for-python - I don't know enough python to say for sure that you can not do better than what you wrote in your question, but I would be very surprised.

Comment: Sorry, I simplified the question, hence getting perfectly good answers that don't match my scenario: [I look for similar values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749106/most-efficient-method-to-get-key-for-similar-values-in-a-dict) and not identical values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ignoring the possibility that samb8s raises, that multiple keys exist for a single value, you can easily reverse the dictionary like this:

```
reverse_dic = dict((v, k) for k, v in dic.items())
```

Comment: Or `iteritems` if it is very large.

Comment: this simply flops the dictionary - it doesn't explicitly return the key for a value, as the OP asked.

Comment: @Nate Well, I assumed they would then be able to work out how to look up the item in the new dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension. This code gives you the keys in a list:

```
>>> a
{1: 2, 3: 4, 9: 4, 5: 6, 7: 8}
>>> [key for key, value in a.items() if value == 4]
[3, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return a set of *ALL* keys that have that value - like a filter by value:

```
def find_keys(dic, val):
    return set(k for k,v in dic.items() if v == val)
```

Answer (score 0):

regular dict[key] -> value

```
my_regular_dict = {1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6}
```

reverse lookup, dict[value] -> key

```
my_reverse_lookup = dict([(val, key) for key, val in my_regular_dict.items()])
```