# Most efficient method to get key for similar values in a dict

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of objects:

```
# I have thousands of objects in my real world scenario
dic = {'k1':obj1, 'k2':obj2, 'k3':obj3, ...}
# keys are string
# objs are MyObject
```

*Edit*: Sorry for letting doubt in the question. Here is the exact class and the `like()` function:

```
class MyObject(object):
    def __init__(self, period, dimensions):
        self.id = None
        self.period = period # period is etree.Element
        self.dimensions = dict() # id -> lxml.XMLElements
        for dim in dimensions:
            # there must be only one child: the typed dimension
            self.dimensions[dim.get('dimension')] = dim[0]
        self._hash = None

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, MyObject)
            and self.period == other.period
            and self.dimensions == other.dimensions

    def like(self, other):
        return (other is not None \
            and self.period == other.period \
           and self.dimensions.keys() == other.dimensions.keys())
```

I wonder how I can have the best implementation for finding objects in dictionary `dic` that are similar to a given value `val`. Something equivalent to:

```
def find_keys(dic, val):
    return [v for v in dic if v.like(val))
```

However this method is too slow, because I have thousands of iterations over `find-keys()` and thousands objects in the dictionary.

Right now, I have implemented a `__hash__(self)` on these objects, and added the key as a property:

```
    def __hash__(self):
        if self._hash is None:
            self._hash = hash(self.periodtype) ^ \
                hash(tuple(sorted(self.dimensions.values())))
        return self._hash
```

Then, I have built a lookup dictionary that is

```
hash_dic = { hash(obj1): [obj1], hash(obj2): [obj2, obj3] }
```

And this new search method is much faster:

```
def find_keys_fast(dic, val):
    prefetched=hash_dic[hash(val)]
    return [x.key for x in prefetched if x.like(val)]
```

Since `__hash__` is a native function internally used by Sets and Dictionaries, is there anything faster or more elegant I could do?

Comment: building key basing on hash is nice idea, but i wouldnt override the original hash whit this.

Comment: You don't need to call `hash` explicitly on dictionary keys, it's done automatically.

Comment: but what exactly is going on? tell us more about your problem, how does the like function look like? I can't see how clustering by `x` helps you as you don't use it in `like` method at all.

Comment: @rds Looking at the diverse responses, it's pretty clear that no one really knows what is being asked. Please try to clarify, if you can.

Comment: to all, thanks for reading the question. I understand it was not precise enough and have given as much details as I could.

Comment: @Adam Jurczyk Why shouldn't I override __hash__ ?

Comment: @tomasz Good understanding. I am actually clistering on some of the properties used in like.

Comment: @rds: I gather that you want to partition *all* your objects into classes of objects that are like each other.  Is this correct?  Or do you want to generally find the objects that are similar to a given one, just for a few objects?  This point is important, because which method is optimal depends on your problem.

Comment: @rds because (IMO) it violated rules from ref: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that we can see the implementation of `like`, a quite simple approach seems feasible---far simpler than my other answer, for one. Define a new `signature` method on `MyObject`:

```
def signature(self):
    return (self.period, frozenset(self.dimensions.keys()))
```

And then iterate through the objects:

```
import collections
sig_keys = collections.defaultdict(set)
for k, obj in dic.iteritems():
    sig_keys[obj.signature()].add(k)
```

With that, `sig_keys.values()` gives all the sets of identifiers for objects which are alike. Lists of objects could instead be directly constructed, if that would better:

```
sig_objs = collections.defaultdict(list)
for obj in dic.itervalues():
    sig_objs[obj.signature()].append(obj)
```

If you want, you could define `__hash__` to `return hash(self.signature())` or the equivalent.

Comment: I Have reimplemented my program using this solution. In terms of performance, it is very close to the hash solution I was exposing in my question. The benefit of this solution is that it becomes unnecessary to define `find_keys_fast()` since it is simply `hash_dic[val.signature()]`. The disadvantage is that `signature()` is not a python function (contrary to `__hash__()` and it's pending `hash()`). Overall, I think the code is more redable than it was originally. Thanks for your thoughts on this topic.

Answer (score 3):

Since I don't know the structure of your data or the nature of the similarity you are seeking, I can only guess at what might work. But perhaps you could build some kind of [prefix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) using dictionaries. As in:

```
trie = {'a':{'b':{'e':{}, 's':{}}, 'c':{'t':{}, 'k':{}}}}
```

These are most commonly used for looking up strings with common prefixes, but perhaps there's some sense in which the data in your objects can be represented as a string. This seems like it would work especially well if there's some order the data can be put in such that earlier data in the string must compare as `==`. I think I can even imagine the leaves of the trie including all similar, rather than all strictly equivalent, objects.

A small toy example of how to work with a trie:

```
>>> trie = {'a':{'b':{'e':{}, 's':{}}, 'c':{'t':{}, 'k':{}}}}
>>> def rec_print(trie, accum=''):
...     if trie:
...         for k in trie:
...             rec_print(trie[k], accum + k)
...     else:
...         print accum
... 
>>> rec_print(trie)
ack
act
abs
abe
```

Comment: An [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) might also be useful for finding objects based on lt/gt relationships.

Comment: Actually, scratch that, that's not what [`OrderedDict`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0372/#questions-and-answers)s are for. (Search for 'sort' to see what I mean.)

Comment: Yes, I can make a string signature of `MyObject`, as such a PrefixTree sounds like a good data structure.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach looks quite good to me *if* you only want the like objects of a few objects.

There is also nothing wrong with defining `__hash__()` for your *own* class.

If you want to group *all* your objects in classes of "like" objects, then there is a faster approach: you can use the **transitivity** of your `like()` method.  In fact, if `like(obj0, obj1)` and `like(obj1, obj2)` are true, then `like(obj0, obj2)` is automatically true, with no need for further calculations.  This means that you can directly group all your objects in classes with the efficient

```
signature = lambda obj: (obj.period, obj.typed_dimensions.keys())
sorted_objs = sorted(dic.values(), key=signature)
objs_in_like_classes = [list(group) for (_, group) in itertools.groupby(sorted_objs, key=signature)]
```

This groups like objects together, automatically.  This is simpler, and is likely faster than defining `__hash__()` and `__eq__()` and doing the prefetching by yourself, because `groupby()` uses the transitivity of `==`.

(**PS**: I prefer Michael J. Barber's "dictionary of like objects grouped by hashable signature" approach to this solution, because it is probably a tad faster, and is also more general, as no sorting is necessary.)

If you need to keep your current approach, you can do it in a slightly cleaner way: you could check whether you really need any of these `if other is not None` tests.  If you want to handle comparisons (`__eq__`) properly, you should also handle the case of `other` being of a different class (instead of checking only for identity with `None`); an `isinstance()` would do.  `like()` might be different, if you only ever compare objects of class `MyObject`.  In this case, your code should look something like:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, MyObject):
        return (self.period == other.period
                and self.typed_dimensions == other.typed_dimensions)
    else:
        return False

def like(self, other):
    return (self.period == other.period  # No need for a backslash
            and self.typed_dimensions.keys() == other.typed_dimensions.keys())
```

This would make the code cleaner (but not really faster).

You could make your `__hash__()` function a tad faster by *not* doing `self._hash = None` in `__init__()` and by writing:

```
def __hash__(self):
    try:
        return self._hash
    except AttributeError:
        self._hash = (hash(self.periodtype) ^
                      hash(tuple(sorted(self.dimensions.values()))))
        return self._hash
```

In fact, `try` is fast when no exception is raised (which is the most common case by far, in your case).

As for your `hash_dict`, it can be constructed quite efficiently with:

```
hash_dict = dict(itertools.groupby(dic.values(), key=hash))
```

(maybe that's what you are already doing).

Comment: This is getting good. I didn't know the itertools, and I think it can be faster than by handmade iteration. Thanks for the other code tricks. Just a remark, the dictionary keys are not hashable, I need to keep my hash function or change your lambda with a fronzenset or a tuple of sorted values.

Comment: Although I like the idea, I don't think `groupby` will work here. The objects won't generally be sorted, so you could get multiple groups with the same keys, only the last of which will appear in the dictionary.

Comment: @rds: You're right.  I thought that `groupby()` did equality comparisons.  In this case, you might want to write your own `groupby()` function that takes the transitivity into account (you would group objects in sets of like objects, and only test the likeliness of a single object from each set), possibly with the help of your hash function, if you want speed.

Comment: @EOL: You had it right initially---`groupby` uses equality for grouping. The key function needs to return a hashable result so that the `dict` call doesn't have a problem.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks. :)  I updated the answer so as to remove the problematic (and useless) `dict()`.

Comment: @EOL: I still don't think it works. You won't have problems with the hashing, but you can have disjoint groups that have the same key value---groupby assumes the objects are sorted by the same key it groups by, which won't generally be the case for the objects from `dic.values()`. You need a `sort`, or just accumulate into a dict with a modified key function, as in my (second, shorter) answer.

Comment: @Michael J. Barber, @EOL, I thought the same thing -- the input into `groupby` has to be sorted (and so _sortable_) for it to produce the expected result. As an example where this could fail, consider four objects, each `like` one another, but two with `a.x > a.y` and two with `b.y > b.x`. Sorting on tuples of attributes could interleave these values with other, unlike values -- say, with `c.x == a.x` but with `c.y` much greater than either `a.x` or `b.x`. More concisely, `like` needs to correspond, _I think_, to a "[total order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order)".

Comment: @Michael, @senderle: good point, about `groupby` requiring sorted values.  @Michael: sorting first before using `groupby` is slower than your answer, I guess, so +1 from me.  :)  @senderle: In the particular case of this question, I don't see why sorting on the tuple used by `like()` shouldn't work (I agree that in general, the sort function should be made compatible with the equality test, though).

Comment: @Michael: I think that your "dictionary of like objects grouped by hashable signature" solution is faster and more general than mine.

Comment: @EOL, you're right, somehow I missed the update explaining the exact implementation of `like`.

Comment: Thanks for your tips and tricks in this answer. Eventually, I like Michael J. Barber's answer better.

Comment: @rds: Yeah, I think that J. Barber's answer is very good (+1 from me!). :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly follow your prefetch step, as you didn't explain it in detail, but maybe you could just as well precompute the complete result?

Another possibility, which I would have done, if the `like` method really looks like that is indexing over the `y` values.

Something like `index = { 10 : [obj1], 12 : [obj2, obj3] ,... }` where they keys are the objects' `y` attribute. Hence, you end up with:

```
def find_keys_in_constant_time(dic, val):
    precomputed = index[val.y]
    return precomputed
```

Of course, it also returns the original `val` object, but so does your original method.

Comment: Unfornuately not, the like method is compelex; I have edited the question to reflect the situation.

Comment: Would prefetching be equivalent to caching? I think prefetching would take a huge time anyway.

Comment: Not equivalent, but similar. Prefetching means to compute it all, before you need it. Caching means to store it for when you need it again. So prefetching is a kind of caching.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE** After seeing the implementation of `like`, the method described is seen to be more complicated than necessary. I'll leave it here, as the approach can be generalized to fuzzier similarity measures, e.g., at least 50% of the dimensions must be the same.

What you're doing looks a lot like an [inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index), although it's impossible to say without really knowing how `like` is implemented. For an inverted index, you use possible object values as the dictionary keys, mapping to lists (or other collections) of objects taking those values. With several properties, you can make several dictionaries, handling the different types of object values. You then look up all the properties for the object in the inverted index, determining an aggregate similarity for each object based on all properties.

To take full advantage of the inverted index, it's better to think of returning all similar objects from one function. This helps you handle each possible "like" objects just once. As an extreme example, you might have an object like another only if all properties are the same; similar objects are then those objects found in all corresponding lists from the inverted index. To get all of the similar objects, you could just convert the lists to sets and take the intersection.

Here's what it might look like in Python, slightly abbreviated to focus on the dimensions---extension to include `period` should be easy. There is a mapping from object identifier strings to the objects in `dic`. You can thus build an inverted index by mapping from the dimensions to sets of the object identifiers that have that dimension. It might be done so:

```
import collections
invind = collections.defaultdict(set)
for k, obj in dic.iteritems():
    for d in obj.dimensions:
        invind[d].add(k)
```

Now say that you want to find all objects that have identical dimensions to a specific object `test_obj`. Just look up the sets of object identifiers with at least one of the dimensions, and take the intersection of all those sets. A concise way to write such a query is:

```
import operator
similar_keys = reduce(operator.and_, [invind[d] for d in test_ojb.dimensions])
similar_objects = [dic[k] for k in similar_keys]
```

The `operate.and_` will calculate the set intersections, `reduce` extends it to the whole list of sets. This is not generally the fastest approach to implement the intersections; instead you can manipulate a set of results in-place with the `intersection_update` method of sets, stopping early once the set is empty---I'll leave the details, as they're easy but verbose.

The advantage of this approach is that any objects with no dimensions in common will not be compared *at all*. Depending on how your dimensions occur, it could be a dramatic reduction in the number of tests made. You can take the idea further, e.g., using pairs of co-occuring dimensions as the keys in the inverted index. This is more expensive to generate the keys, but generally reduces the sizes of the sets of object identifiers---a bit of experimentation, or just a good understanding of the dimensions, should help to make the right tradeoff.

To include the periods in the comparisons, just add another inverted index mapping periods to sets of object identifiers. Extending the query for similar objects should be straightforward.

Comment: I think it is exactly what I do with my `hash_dic`. But instead of taking a given property as the key, I use the hash of the object. I do this because the main property is a dictionary which itself is not hashable.

Comment: @rds Given that you only use the dictionary keys in your `like` method, you could instead use a `frozenset`, which is hashable. For an inverted index, however, you'd want to use the keys of `typed_dimensions` as the keys in the index, mapping to lists of tuples containing the objects and the corresponding value for that key and object. Hashability ceases to be an issue with this structure.

Comment: Can you detail what I should replace by the `frozenset`?

Comment: @rds I wouldn't, actually, that was more a general comment on how you might deal with non-hashable dictionaries; sorry that wasn't clearer. I'd use the inverted index. I'll add some example code.

Comment: Yet `hash(frozenset(self.dimensions.values()))` is faster than `hash(tuple(sorted(self.dimensions.values()))))` :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer he question, as I have no idea what are you requirements. What I would do is creating some kind of Related class and populate your items with it. How to implement it mainly depends on properties of you `like` function. If your relationship is symmetrical (i.e. a is like b if and only if b is like a), than you can cluster related items and instead of iterating items, you iterate clusters and compare with any item within it; if it matches, all items within cluster are in relationship with your element.

However, the relationship from you example is not symmetrical, so you probably need another approach. You still could cluster by `y` and `z`, and on looking up element taking intersection of corresponding `cluster_y` with union of `cluster_z`'s holding z's greater or equal to element being looked up. However, it might add significant memory overhead if the values differs much.

And you could do something else by examining your relationship properties. We could help if you provided more details.

Comment: My relationship is  actually symetrical. I had the idea of clustering, and my clusters are build with the __hash__ method. Maybe this is what should be improved?