# Change the value of a dictionary to key of a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, key, key-value

I want to create a "real" dictionary: a Dutch to English dictionary with the following words:
def reversTranslation(dictionary):

```
>>> dictionary= {'tension': ['spanning'], 'voltage': ['spanning', 'voltage']}
>>> dictionary= reverseTranslation(dictionary)
>>> dictionary
{'spanning': ['tension', 'voltage'], 'voltage': ['voltage']}
```

As you can see in dutch 'spanning' has two different meanings in English. 
Help will be appreciated.

Comment: So the question is...

Comment: The python is valid, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
def reverseTranslation(d):
    return dict((v1,[k for k,v in d.iteritems() if v1 in v])
                for v1 in set(sum(d.values(),[])))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to obtain that result, the most readable way is:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def reverse_dictionary(dictionary):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for key, meanings in dictionary.iteritems():  #or just .items()
        for meaning in meanings:
            result[meaning].append(key)
    return result
```

Or you can first sum up the values and then iterate on the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
d= {'tension': ['spanning'], 'voltage': ['spanning', 'voltage'],'extra':['voltage']}
val = set(reduce(list.__add__,d.values()))

dict={}
for x in val:
    tmp={x:[]}
    for k,v in d.items():
        if x in v:
           tmp[x].append(k)
    dict.update(tmp)

print dict
```

Note: collections are available only from python 2.4 and later